# How to execute set of tasks in parallel in TFS Release Definition

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have set of tasks in my release definition some of the tasks executes for few minutes and are not depended on any other tasks. Is there a way I can run these tasks in parallel for a given environment in Release definition.

I did tried creating a separate environment and executed the tasks as a separate environment, but that doesn't solves the purpose. I would want to execute these tasks in a same environment but in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to execute set of tasks in parallel in TFS Release Definition

This idea is reasonable. But, AFAIK, there are not parallel tasks in the VSTS build and release process at this moment.

There is a uservoice item for it and many community members who have the same request as you:

[Ability to run tasks in parallel](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365659/ability-to-run-tasks-in-parallel.html)

You can vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

Hope this helps.